# C# Picturebox leaves a white trail when moved

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a timer to move a `PictureBox` inside a form. The picturebox leaves a white trail behind it which disappears when the picturebox stops. Is there any way to get rid of the white trail? I've tried `this.Invalidate();` which removed the trail but caused the whole form to flimmer until the picturebox stopped.

If anyone could help me solve this problem I would be grateful!

Comment: Do you get the same problem after this.Refresh();?

Comment: You mean timer changes location of a `PictureBox` control within the form? What is the interval of this timer? Why do you want to move this `PictureBox` with a timer? Some more details could be helpful. As a quick fix, try to set `DoubleBuffered` property on the form to `true` to prevent flickering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally much more difficult to do animations in WinForms than in WPF, because WinForms was not designed to support animations.

Have a look at the open source library Dot Net Transitions that provides some animation functionality to WinForms

> The Transitions library lets you create animated transitions of any properties of user-interface elements for .NET. It provides an easy way to perform UI animations in .NET in a similar way to the Core Animation library for Apple and the iPhone.

http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/